# MySQL best datatype for start and end time?

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset I need to create and upload into a MySQL table. My data has start and end times of classes, such as "8:00 AM" & "3:15 PM". Is it a better idea to store times as datetime format with generic date or convert the AM/PM format to 24hr and store as time?

Comment: read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: I'd go with datetime

Comment: When you only need the time, you obviously store it as time (convert it to 24hr format).